# Exporting data from LabView

Tags: labview

I have been using LabView to capture some long-time data and then process them into MATLAB. So, I was manually exporting data from Labview to excel. But, I have found that the Labview does not export more than 1048575 data to excel which in my case corresponds to roughly 47 seconds. For my task, I need to capture data of at least more than two minutes. As a result, I am unable to process the signal expectedly.

I am assuming, my Labview does not store more than 1048575 data at a time. I have tried increasing the input resolution, but I do not think that is a solution. Is there any way, I can export all my data to excel at once? Thank you.

Comment: _"Labview does not export more than 1048575 data to excel"_ How are you exporting data to Excel -- can you post your code?

Comment: Are you right clicking on a graph/chart and exporting to Excel?

Comment: Yes. Also, I tried adding a "write a measurement pallet" on the block diagram. Both of them doing the same thing.

Comment: @Joe Friedrichsen I have created the Labview program in block diagram format. I can send you the file through email if that is ok

Comment: I just want to clarify that LabVIEW is a programming environment... it knows NOTHING about Excel. The questioner is using some library to talk to Excel. It might be just writing a spreadsheet directly, it might be using the NI Report Generation tools, or it might be using any number of 3rd party libraries. As phrased, this question is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

For large data sets, my recommendation is to save samples to disk as they are acquired, and LabVIEW installs a few examples to demonstrate how.

## Example

**Write Tab-Delimited File.vi**
[image: LabVIEW block diagram of example VI for writing data to a spreadsheet]
Location: `[labview root]\examples\File IO\Spreadsheet\Tab-Delimited Data\Write Tab-Delimited File.vi`

The key points for this approach:

1. Use the [File I/O VIs](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/file_vis_and_functions/) to create, open, write, and close your data file.
2. Use [`Array To Spreadsheet String.vi`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/array_to_spreadsheet_str/) to convert your sample data to decimal strings

Answer (score 0):

Excel [does not support more than 1048576 rows on a spreadsheet](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), so you cannot save more than this quantity of data in an Excel spreadsheet (`.xls` or `.xlsx`) file.

Joe Friedrichsen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51073212/24447) is a good suggestion: using this approach you should be able to load the data into MATLAB using [`dlmread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) and specifying `'\t'` as the delimiter.

Alternatively you could use LabVIEW's [Write To Measurement File](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvexpress/write_lv_measurement_file/) express VI, but configure it to write in the `Text (LVM)` format. Then you ought to be able to load the data into MATLAB using this [LVM file import](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19913-lvm-file-import) code from the MATLAB File Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to also simply create multiple excel files, incrementing the filename when you hit the size limit.  This lets you keep other excel content (like formulas, graphs, macros) but just limit the data set you pass to excel.

Another option is to run a data smoothing or averaging algorithm in LabVIEW and pass less data to excel for reporting.  If you ran a 10 point averaging filter for example, you would have 1/10th the lines in excel needed, as long as that data still represents the results close enough for your needs.